# How can Reusable Blocks be fully deleted?

Tags: block-editor, trash

All of the reusable blocks on one of my sites were deleted last week. Not just deleted, but the trash emptied. I've already had a security vendor audit the site, and they concluded there was no hack, it was done by a legitimate user. No one was using the database directly, so it had to be done in wp-admin.

The only way I can find for reusable blocks to be completely deleted is to visit the page `http://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_status=trash&post_type=wp_block`. (On that page there are 3 ways to permanently delete: an Empty Trash button, individual Delete links, and a Bulk Actions to delete all that are checked.)

Is there some other way in wp-admin that all the blocks could be completely deleted?